# If the solution of the following ODE unique with given initial value?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the following ODE:

$$t\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=F(f,g)$$$$t\frac{d}{dt}g(t)=G(f,g)$$.

F,G are polynomials.

For given an initial value $f(0)=f_*,g(0)=g_*$ satisfying $F(f_*,g_*)=0,G(f_*,g_*)=0$, could we prove that f(t) and g(t) are constant functions? Or say does the solution to this initial value unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

we can make the change of variable $t=e^s$, then this problem becomes a problem ask about the limit of the ODE, the initial value problem will not be unique.